# Где скачать хорошую книгу по Visual Studio 2005?

Tags: visual-studio

Интерфейс на английском,не все помню и понимаю в меню.

Comment: Старовата версия. Начинайте сразу с VS 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Секреты Visual Studio (блог Сары Форд)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/rusaraford/)

Answer (score 2):

Скачивать и вообще читать литературу по Visual Studio надо на сайте Microsoft. Вообще в библиотеке MSDN есть все необходимое для работы с продуктами Microsoft, в том числе и на русском языке. Конкретно по Visual Studio:

- [Приступая к работе с Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/vstudio/ff431702)
- [Ресурсы для обучения использованию Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd831853.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Уже есть более новая VS 2010 и книги по ней тоже. Отличия от 2005 есть, конечно, но в остальном всё тоже самое. А скачать можно, например, на www.progbook.ru для различных версий. И если вы программист - обязательно выучите английский!

Comment: Я знаю разговорный анлийский (кажется, что даже лучше чем русский), А вот в техническом приходится и со словарем иногда посидеть.